# not working present modalview controller using parentview class

Tags: iphone

I want to go main viewcontroller. Actually I created three views,i.e, barchart view,piechart view,gridview.
For these 3 views parent control is bar chart view. 
Actually I am getting data another reportgrid class to gridview.
 here parentview is gridview.I will show grid info in tableview.
When I tap tableview it will reload from reportgrid to gridview.
 But grid view how can I implement present modal for 3 classes parent is bar chart. in my app for all controllers, parentview is main view. In my app I didn't use navigation controller.
I used one user defined methods.

reportgrid.m

```
#pragma mark - Button Click

-(void)btnClicked:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self.mainviewcont click:sender];
}
```

grid view .m for i pad

```
-(void)click:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [Database_operations setRetailerId:AccountNumber];
    [Database_operations setDate:[dateArray objectAtIndex:[[sender superview] tag]]];

    if (report) 
    {
        [Database_operations removeallsubviews:report.view];
        report=nil;
    }
     *popup;
reportsubview *report;
    if (reportPop) 
    {
        [reportPop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
        reportPop=nil;
    }
    report=[[ReportSubView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReportSubView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    report.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 900, 700);
    reportPop=[[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:report];
    report.popover=reportPop;
    reportPop.delegate=report;
    reportPop.popoverContentSize=CGSizeMake(900, 700);
    [reportPop presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.center.x, self.view.center.y, sender.frame.size.width, sender.frame.size.height) inView:sender.superview permittedArrowDirections:nil animated:YES];
}
```

for iphone app how to implement present modal view controller

Answer (score 0):

present modal view controller is deprecated in iOS 6 better you can try 
**presentViewController**

use like

present modal view controller

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    [self presentModalViewController:viewController animated:NO];        
}
```

presentviewcontroller

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
  [self presentViewController:presentModalViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

in your code try this **click** method

```
-(void)click:(UIButton *)sender
{
      if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    [Database_operations setRetailerId:AccountNumber];
    [Database_operations setDate:[dateArray objectAtIndex:[[sender superview] tag]]];

    if (report) 
    {
        [Database_operations removeallsubviews:report.view];
        report=nil;
    }



    reportsubview *repor=[[ReportSubView alloc] initWithNibName:@"ReportSubView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    report.view.frame=[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
  [self presentViewController:report animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
}
```

Comment: how to implement presentviewcontroller in instance method by using parentview controller for iphone?

Comment: To access the parent View controller u can use self.parentViewController

and to implement presentviewcontroller
 use  
 [self.parentViewController presentViewController:v animated:NO completion:nil];

Comment: actually my parentclass is barchartview. coming to gridview ,gridview parent class is reportgrid class. so,how can write single method for all these controls and to ipmplement prsent maodal navigation in iphone

Comment: yeah. i am getting subview by using presentview controler. but I am getting in screen with segmaentcontrol. i used segment control in main viewcontroler.mainviewcontroler is parent class for all classes in my app.in main view i put segment,upadate btn,hologram images, logout btn. I want to remove these things when i used presentviewcontroler

Comment: you can hide them when presenting view controller.

Comment: i did simple to go mainviewcontroller. i called obj.parentcontrolerdelegate=self; then it simply hides the mainview,successfully done present view and dismiss view